# Remove numbers from text with R

Tags: r, regex, text-mining

I try to remove numbers from text without using `tm_map` :

```
# remove grammar/punctuation and numbers
Data_clean$Raison.Reco.clean <- tolower(gsub('[[:punct:]]', '', Data_clean$Raison.Reco))
```

Any idea please?

Thank you

Comment: Please provide example input text and expected output.

Comment: This will replace all digits (`\d`) with "" in column `x` of your data frame... `gsub("\\d","",df$x)`

Comment: Ok thank you, `Data_clean$Raison.Reco.clean <- tolower(gsub('[[:punct:]][0-9]+', '', Data_clean$Raison.Reco))`

Comment: You might want `[[:punct:]0-9]` or `[[:punct:]\\d]` instead - your regex will look for a punctuation mark followed by a digit, rather than one or the other.

Comment: @AndrewGustar OK thank you